# Remote Testing with the Stepping Thread Group throws "Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException

Tags: jmeter

Remote Testing with the Normal thread Group test executes successfully.
[image]`Image`
[image]`Image`
[image]`Image`
[image]`Image`
[image]`Image`
[image]`Image`
[image]`Image`
[image]`Image`
[image]`Image`

Please advise me!

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Can you be more specific about running your tests? I mean the first test seems to complete OK, but the second one does not seem to connect to slaves at all. How do you run your tests in this serial mode? Are you sure slaves do not exits after the first test?

Comment: Certainly vernjan! 1.Yes that's what I am saying,i have executed two test of same script one is with the Normal Thread Group and the other one with the stepping Thread Group.Test with the Normal Thread Group ran successfully and with the Stepping Thread Group failed.2.See the attached pom file how I am running.3.To give more clarity this time I have executed tests individually same thing see the attached results file in my original post.Since i cannot add to this commant-Raj

Answer (score 0):

Stepping thread group is part of [JMeter plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/). Please make sure JMeter plugins are installed on both your slaves. According the error it  could be the problem. [Standard set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet/) should be enough.

Comment: Yes I know, Master & Slave nodes has Standard set plugin.Attached the screenshots in original post for your reference.It's my guess only it seems mvn plugin is not working for stepping thread group